# How to create multiple string and integer values from one line in Java using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to read this line in Java - "abc:300:xyz:def", and I'm really unsure how to do this using arrays because in the array format it would be like this: ["abc:300:xyz:def"] . I started with

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("300");
list.add("xyz");
list.add("def");
```

in my constructor, but then I don't know if I add a

```
list.split(":")
```

somewhere, because if so would that be right after I initialize the ArrayList?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Code posted doesn't match question... please clarify.

Comment: `String s = scanner.nextLine(); ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(':'))); ` Is this what you want?

Comment: Please be clear about whether you're trying to read one line or create one line.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch updated it to say create one line!

Comment: @BilltheLizard updated it to say create one line, I didn't realize I mistyped that.

Comment: @Coldspeed but then where do I get to define the strings such as abc, 300, xyz, and def?

Comment: Are you splitting the string "abc:300:xyz:def" into an array (what text says) or are you trying to convert an array to that string (what code seems to want to do)?

Comment: @Tezra I'm trying to do the former

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To join the items, use `String.join`

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("300");
list.add("xyz");
list.add("def");

String str = String.join(":", list);
```

To split the items, use `String.split`

```
ArrayList<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split(":"));
```

Comment: I believe you need to add cast (ArrayList<String>) right before Arrays.asList(str.split(":")), but then you get an error of list being a duplicate variable.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
String line = "abc:300:xyz:def";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(line.split(":"));
```

Now you have a list containing the 4 strings.

Comment: Hmm, I think OP is still a little unclear on what they want to do.

Comment: Then are arrays not used here at all? (I'm really new to this so I'm sorry if I'm asking something that's obvious).

Comment: Arrays are used. `line.split(":")` actually returns an array, but I immediately call `.toList()` which converts an array to a List

Comment: @Aenadon There is no `toList()` method in arrays. Should use `Arrays.asList(line.split(":"))` instead.

Comment: @Bubletan i guess I&#39;m stuck in groovy because I used `.toList()` in groovy today. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

If you have to read a line from console you can try something like this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String yourString = scanner.next();
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(yourString , ":");
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextElement());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only the arrays not the arraylist, you can just use the split method from the string

```
String line = "abc:300:xyz:def";
String[] stringArray = line.split(":");
```